# Import File from File Directory (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

Currently, I have the directory to a file

```
"../Model.py"
```

This model has a class called **Test**.

Using the string of the directory, I want to import and use the class Test.

How do I do so?

(The String will change dynamically)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Two options: make sure those modules are in a known directory, and add that directory to `sys.path`, then use `importlib.import_module(module_name)` to import the modules dynamically. Or, `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location()` as shown in the other linked post.

Answer (score -1):

From: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

I tested this and I believe it should work for you as well. The code should look as follows:

```
import sys
directory = '../Model.py'
directory = directory[:-8]
sys.path.append(directory)
from Model import Test
```